# Data movement across two salesforce instances

Tags: integration, data

I have use case where I need to move data across SF1 table to SF2 table. I want this data movement in a real time. Is there a way I can use any messaging queues. Right now we are using informatica to move the data across but this is not a real time solution. I am running this as a batch process with an interval of 10 mins.

Comment: Are talking about two separate Salesforce objects or two separate databases?  If you mean objects, why not use a formula?  How much data (how many fields) do you need to move?

Answer (score 2):

A couple of options:

- Salesforce to Salesforce functionality; this allows you to push data between Salesforce orgs

  - [Introduction to Salesforce to Salesforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Salesforce_to_Salesforce)
  - [Salesforce to Salesforce Overview](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=business_network_intro.htm)
- Create an Apex trigger code to push the data over to the second org using a callout; This you may come a cropper with API limits etc but depends on what org you have.
- Use Salesforce Outbound Workflow Messages; Fire the workflow on the object that includes all the fields from the object, create a page on the destination org to receive the message and store/update the record.
- Continue using informatica but fire a Salesforce workflow/message directly to informatica to fire the record into the destination org (bit pointless in my opinion).